# How many Harry Potter 20th Anniversary sets are there?

Tags: set-database, harry-potter

I have 3 of the Harry Potter 20th Anniversary sets (76386, 76388 & 76389) which include gold minifigs (I have Harry, Ron & Voldemort), and a number of (depends on which set) purple 2x2 tiles labelled as "Wizard Cards" of which I have 9 of 16.

This got me thinking; how many 20th anniversary Harry Potter sets are there? Do we have a timeline published by Lego of all the sets to be labelled as 20th anniversary, and which will include gold minifigs and wizard cards? And do we know which gold minifigs are out there/coming in future sets?

Comment: The question seems to be a mix of what **is** (which can be answered) and what **will be** (which can only be speculated; even things Lego announces might never make it to market, of course).

Comment: @RSchulz What I mean by "And do we know which gold minifigs are out there/coming in future sets?" is, new sets which have been announced. I don't mean, get your crystal balls out and tell me what's still in design/pre-production/play test etc...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Brickset is very useful in this kind of questions since their catalog items have tags.

You can find details you are looking for by checking items marked with following tags:

- [Lego Harry Potter 20th Anniversary](https://brickset.com/sets/tag-Lego-Harry-Potter-20Th-Anniversary)
- [Collectable Wizard Cards](https://brickset.com/sets/tag-Collectable-Wizard-Cards)

And, obviously, LEGO doesn't disclose plans for upcoming sets unless they are about to be released.